# Writing manually a table of contents with hyperlinks for a document consisting of included ready pdf files

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, pdfpages, hyperlink

I thought this should be an easy task but I have difficulties in getting the pieces together.

For including the pdf files in my document I can use the `pdfpages` package.

For hyperlinks in my document I can use the `hyperref` package. However, I'm stuck at setting up labels and references to the included pages.

What does not work

```
 \hyperlink{mylabel}{\includepdf[pages=1]{pdffile.pdf}} % Throws error
```

What also does not work

```
\phantomsection
\hyperlink{mylabel}{} % No error, but warning: Empty link is ignored
```

Is there some way to make this setup work? Or is there a completely different approach to the underlying problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to include one or more PDF files into your document that consist of more than one page each and link to one of these pages from some other page of your document.

With the `hyperref` package, you can actually link to any page of your document you want, you only need to set a label for this page. Pages can be accessed internally with `page.<page>` where `<page>` is the page number. You essentially need to create a label to such an internal link. This can be done independently from the actual contents of your document (which means, you can even refer to a page that does not exist),

This can be done, for example, as follows (I did not include several pages from another PDF document, but just inserted some text, but anyways, the principle is the same):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\setpagelabel}[1]{%
    % this only works if the `hyperref` package is loaded
    \newlabel{page:#1}{{#1}{#1}{page:#1}{page.#1}{}}%
}

% making pages 2 and 5 accessible by creating a label for them
\setpagelabel{2}
\setpagelabel{5}

\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}
    
    Something is on page \ref{page:2}

    Something else is on page \ref{page:5}
    
    \lipsum[1-20]
    
\end{document}
```

At the very start of the document, two links to the relative pages in the document are placed:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

pdfpages has in-built facilities for links. For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\hyperlink{example-image.pdf.1}{to page 1 of example-image}

\hyperlink{example-image-duck.pdf.6}{to page 6 of example-image-duck}

\includepdf[pages=1,link]{example-image}

\includepdf[pages=5-6,link]{example-image-duck}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Somehow this did not work for me, but maybe I didn't understand how the pages are counted correctly. From your answer it seems the page count in the included pdf document is the correct one, not the page count in the resulting pdflatex document?

Comment: yes, I used page 6 of the one example, and linked to it.